# HttpContext.Current.User is null under windows authentication (integrated pipeline)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

In the web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</configuration>
```

in global.asax

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    tracker.LogRequest(HttpContext.Current.User, DateTime.Now)
    ///THIS IS ALWAYS NULL!!!
}
```

I am just really confused by this, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a symptom of listening on the wrong event. You should probably listen for [Application.PostAuthenticateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postauthenticaterequest.aspx).

Running a sample piece of code using a project I have that authenticates against my local domain's Active Directory to ask if the User object is nothing:

**Code**

```
Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine("Authenticate Request: " & (HttpContext.Current.User Is Nothing))
End Sub

Sub Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine("Post-authenticate Request: " & (HttpContext.Current.User Is Nothing))
End Sub
```

**Output**

> Authenticate Request: True
>
> Post-authenticate Request: False

Following the `PostAuthenticateRequest` event, the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` property is an instance of [`System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericidentity.aspx) for unauthenticated requests.

Comment: oddly any attempt to hook into PostAuthenticateRequest yields a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " in [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) +1116
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb) +89
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189

Comment: I don't think is the source of the problem though since this code has worked on one of my workmate's PCs

Comment: Not according to a brief bit of testing I've done. Unauthenticated contexts do not have User objects until after the post-authenticate event. See the above code and results.

Comment: hmmm, sounds good, although I still can't hook into postauthenticate without a crash.

Comment: Are you being alerted that there is no code associated with the exception? Also, (and this is a bit of a shot in the dark), does your global.asax prototype follow the convention: `void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)`?

Comment: please be aware this is authorize checking in then Authenticate section, you should wait check user in AuthorizeRequest (next in the pipeline)