# Getting Object not found for formsIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to set a authetication request based on my ticket created in login.aspx but for some reason I getting an error the code is as follows

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an Identity object
        FormsIdentity identity = (FormsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;
        // When the ticket was created, the UserData property was assigned a
        // pipe delimited string of role names.
        string[] roles = identity.Ticket.UserData.Split(new char[] { ',' });
        String userData = identity.Ticket.UserData;
        // This principal will flow throughout the request.
        GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);
        // Attach the new principal object to the current HttpContext

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to go from `Application_AuthenticateRequest()`, to the next function in the pipeline:

`Application_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)`

At this stage windows authentication should be completed becouse at `Application_AuthenticateRequest()` it is still `null`. Basic information about pipeline order can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis) and nice visualization diagram [here](http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf)

Also as fallows if you are runnig with IIS 7 and asp.net 4.0 you should call all login requests inside:

`Application_PostAuthenticateRequest() (object sender, EventArgs e)`

as in [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619763/httpcontext-current-user-is-null-under-windows-authentication-integrated-pipeli)